# Nicematrix overbrace and underbrace clash with surrounding text

Tags: matrices, arrays, braces, nicematrix

I am surprised that I didn't find anything on this topic here. In the following document, the contents of the braces clash with the above text even after several compilations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,nicematrix}
\begin{document}
    A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A 
    \[
        \begin{pNiceMatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
        11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
        \CodeAfter
        \OverBrace{1-1}{2-3}{A\rule{1em}{7ex}}
        \OverBrace{1-4}{2-6}{B}
        \end{pNiceMatrix}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any chance to resolve this automatically, without inserting a `rule` or `vspace` manually?

Comment: Same issue with `\UnderBrace`.

Comment: Judging by the implementation of these commands, they explicitly use what in TikZ is `remember picture` and `overlay`. Meaning it will never reserve any space on its own. (All examples in the manual have a taller code example besides them so it's not noticeable there.) Maybe, it can be solved by using submatrices and/or the `first-row` key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a rather complicated workaround. Load `tikz` with the libraries `decorations.pathreplacing` and `calligraphy`. Then place the brace using `\Hdotsfor{<num columns>}` in row 1 (option `first-row`), but change the `line-style` using `calligraphic brace`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix, mathtools, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}
\tikzset{mybrace/.style={thick, decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=1.5mm, raise=-1mm}}}

\begin{document}
    A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A 
    \[
        \begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row]
        \Hdotsfor{3}[line-style=mybrace, shorten=0pt]^{\textstyle A}&\Hdotsfor{3}[line-style={mybrace},shorten=0pt]^{\textstyle B}\\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
        11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16
        \end{pNiceMatrix}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The package `nicematrix` never reserve space for the elements constructed by `\OverBrace` and `UnderBrace`.

Here is a construction which ensures that the vertical space between the text and the equation is the same as expected with standard LaTeX (the braces are constructed in an overlapping position but not the labels, which are in a ``first row'').

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,nicematrix}
\begin{document}
    A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A 
    \[
        \begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row]
        \rule[-8pt]{0pt}{8pt}
        \Block{1-3}{A} & & & \Block{1-3}{B} \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
        11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
        \CodeAfter
        \OverBrace[shorten,yshift=3pt]{1-1}{2-3}{}
        \OverBrace[shorten,yshift=3pt]{1-4}{2-6}{}
        \end{pNiceMatrix}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]